# Rails: automatically add "and" as a view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a function like:

`collection([1,2,3]) # '1, 2, and 3.'`

I think function collection or something similar is defined somewhere in the Rails helpers but I can't find it.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `to_sentence`

https://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence

Answer (score 0):

[`to_sentence`](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) will do most of what you have asked:

`[1,2,3].to_sentence # => "1, 2, and 3"`

Punctuation needs to be added yourself:

```rb
[1,2,3].to_sentence + "." # => "1, 2, and 3."
# OR
"#{[1,2,3].to_sentence}." # => "1, 2, and 3."
```

If you want your sentence capitalised (doesn't apply in your example) you can use `.humanize`:

```rb
["one", "two", "three"].to_sentence # => "one, two, and three"
["one", "two", "three"].to_sentence.humanize # => "One, two, and three"
```